mysql general log generates a lot of data so that it burdens the server
My IT team recently activated the MySQL general log to meet regulatory requirements. However, we’ve encountered significant performance issues:

After 20+ hours of activation, the general log generated over 3 million rows.
Today, when my team attempted to query the general log data, our application failed to load the logs.
Our Grafana dashboard showed 100% CPU usage during the issue.

Our database server has the following hardware specifications:

vCPU
GB RAM

It’s clear that the current hardware is insufficient to handle the load caused by the general log. I’ve explored alternatives like using Fluentd to forward logs, but I’m unsure if this is the right approach.
Here my current mysql general log configuration
general_log_file       = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
general_log            = 1
log_output             = 'table'

Here are my questions:

Should I consider upgrading the server hardware, or is there a better way to manage the general log efficiently?
Are there any best practices or tools that can help offload and process the MySQL general log data without impacting server performance?


I suggest, review the use of general log to mean the regulatory requirement and examine other options.

@danblack do you have any different options? currently im also already activate audit logs but it still not enough to meet the requirements.

I don't even know what the requirement is.  Binary logs can record changes in records.

@danblack the requirement is we need to activate mysql general log. but then it give us problem to displaying logs in webapps.

I don't recommend saving the general log into tables as it will have a significant impact on the performance of MySQL. You should set the log_output to File to store the general log in files. You can use some log tools to collect it in real time and then analyze it instead of querying the mysql.general_log of MySQL. Both reading from and writing to the mysql.general_log will consume I/O cpu and thus affect the performance of MySQL.

how about elk stack to processing logs? or do you have any other recommendations?

Yes, ELK is highly suitable. It is an open-source and free solution for log collection, analysis, and presentation. Then, there are some open-source projects on GitHub for analyzing MySQL SLOW Queries. You can also take a look at them.

Definitely you need to deploy on server hardware that is capable of serving your traffic. If you have a regulatory requirement to keep query logs, then that's what you need to do.
You could process query logs on a different server. This is what I'd do. It would reduce the impact on your database.
First, use file-based query logging. log_output=file.

Once a day, rename query.log to query-YYYYMMDD.log
Run SQL statement FLUSH LOGS;. This closes the old log file, and creates a new log file with the original name.
scp the dated log file to your log-archive server, where you can do whatever you want with it.
Remove the old log file on your database server, after you verify it was copied to the other server successfully.

You might want to investigate using a log-search product such as Graylog or another product. Check them out and do some proof of concept tests to see which one meets your needs. Stack Overflow is not a place for technology product recommendations, because you know your needs better than us. It's up to you to evaluate several options.
You said your application "experienced errors" when searching the log file, but that's not enough description to make a guess at what a solution could be. It's like telling your auto mechanic that your car "makes a funny sound."

i've ELK stack service in one of my server. Can i used it? But, what kind of integration i need to use? Because mysql log from elk stack only can display error and slow query log.

I have not done this, so I can't speak from experience. But I just Googled "elk mysql general query log" and found this: https://logstail.com/blog/how-to-analyze-mysql-logs-with-elk-stack-and-logstail-com/ I'm sure there are other solutions. Or you may need to write a simple script to make your own integration. It's not rocket science.
